# How do I use multiple classes without having multiple connections?

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

In the pages so far, I have had used one connection class and one class to hold the logic for the page. However, I now have a page where I need to use multiple classes based on different scenarios that may happen.

This is what I have been able to make work, but it seems like bad practice. I've searched around but can't find a solution. So my question is, what is a better way of what I'm trying to do.

```
<?php
require 'class/connect.php';
$db = new Connect();
require 'class/normal-page.php';
require 'class/get-page.php';
?>

    <?php if (!isset($_GET['id'])) { ?>
        <?php $normalpage = new NormalPage($db); ?>
    <?php
        } else {
        $id = $_GET["id"];
        $getpage = new Getpage($id, $db);
    ?>

        <h1><?php echo $getpage->getTitle(); ?></h1>
        <p><?php echo $getpage->getDescription(); ?></p>
    <?php } ?>


class Normalpage {

    function __construct($db) {

        $query = 'SELECT something FROM table';
        $result = $db->query($query);
}
}
```

Hope that's enough info to make sense. So in short, I include the connect class and use the variable in both other classes.

Comment: In addition to @nickb's answer, I would recommend you look into autoloading of classes. That way you don't have to specify which class files you have to include, as they are loaded automatically, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: I think you can make your life a little bit easier with [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.autoload.php) as well. **Edit:** Like jeroen wrote, same time, same idea ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a proper way of dealing with the database object. In fact, it is called the [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) design pattern, and is actually quite common. You might want to consider saving the constructor parameter `$db` to a member variable so other class methods may access the database via something like `$this->db` if you declare the member variable as `private $db;`.

However, you might want to consider the [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_design_pattern) design pattern, as it will help organize the classes for your pages. See this example from the above link:

```
class Factory
{
    public static function build($type)
    {
        $class = 'Format' . $type;
        if (!class_exists($class)) {
            throw new Exception('Missing format class.');
        }
        return new $class;
    }
}

class FormatString {}
class FormatNumber {}

try {
    $string = Factory::build('String');
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

try {
    $number = Factory::build('Number');
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Also, you could have a look at making Connect a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) or just replacing `$db` with a static class variable on `Connect`. This would mean you could always access your $db variable as `Connect::db` or `Connect::db()`.

Comment: You'll run into trouble with singletons when having to deal with multiple DB connections at the same time.